# How to add css class to approved comment

Tags: wordpress

In my theme, I use `wp_list_comments()` to display comments, I want to add a css class to new approved comment, I have tried to find a filter or something like this but couldn't find anything. Does anyone has a solution to do it, I don't want to edit in `wp-includes/comment-template.php`. Thank a lot!

Comment: I guess the question is how the system would tell if it's a "new approved comment", who is it new to and since when? You may need a plugin for this, but I might be wrong... my 2 cents...

Comment: @webeno the new approved comment is the newest one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Will Find Code Into **`wp-includes/comment-template.php`**

Into Line 1997

```
<div class="comment-content">
<?php comment_text(); ?>
</div><!-- .comment-content -->
```

Add Your Custom HTML Here

---

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    comment_form();
    echo str_replace('class="comment-form"','class="comment-form your-custom-class"',ob_get_clean());
?>
```

**Now the standard class comment-form will be replaced by itself plus the custom class.**

Comment: Thank you for such a helpful answer, but i want to do in my theme, not in core

Comment: but which hook? do you know anyone?

Comment: Please give me a fully example, I don't know how to use `comment_class()`

Comment: Ok, i will try it. Thank you